# querying ScriptDb records with Array values

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to query all records in my ScriptDB database with Array values that contain a specific entry? For e.g. my record structure looks like this {Name: 'Fred', Titles: ['Captain', 'MVP']}

Is it possible to query all records that have 'MVP' in it's title? I mean, other than that looping through all the entries in the database?

Thank You,
Vish

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

There's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1733) opened regarding this. You may want to *star* it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.